# jquery prevent multi selection in multi-select

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I everybody,

I've a multi-select like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="lista">
    <option value="a">Mario</option>
    <option value="b">Maria</option>
    <option value="c">Mark</option>
</select>
```

How can I prevent to select multiple option by a user? (*shift+arrow up/down*)

thanks in advance

ciao
h.

Comment: Why are you using this control type if you don't want the behaviour that goes with it?

Comment: Why not remove multiple="multiple" ?

Comment: @haltman if it's purely for esthetic reasons, then you can get the same effect with the size attribute

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not sure why you can't simply remove `multiple="multiple"` in the HTML, here's how you would do it with jQuery:

```
// Wait until the DOM is loaded
$(function(){
    $('#lista').removeAttr("multiple");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide size attribute to it..

```
<select id="lista" size="3">
    <option value="a">Mario</option>
    <option value="b">Maria</option>
    <option value="c">Mark</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should remove the multiple attribute as this will still allow the user to select multiple